# OutlinedButton dissapears when conditional Text is displayed - Android Kotlin JetPack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I develop Android for a couple years but I just switched to Jetpack Compose. I have a hard time...

But let's jump into the problem:

I have an OutlinedButton to add stuff to the database.
On top is a conditional part which is displayed when a switch "Recurring" is selected.

This part consist of a Row and a Text, which is also displayed conditionally, when the submitted value of the Text in the Row is invalid. When the error text is displayed, the add Button is not displayed anymore.

How it looks on the device, before displaying an error
[image: Screenshot of how it looks before displaying error]

Here is my CodeSnippet:

```kotlin
if (mainViewModel.recurring) {
    Row() {
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = mainViewModel.recurringPeriod,
            onValueChange = {
                mainViewModel.recurringPeriod = it
                mainViewModel.onEvent(AddTransactionEvent.OnPeriodChanged(it))
            },
            isError = state.periodError != null,
            keyboardOptions =
                KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done, keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
            modifier = Modifier.weight(0.2f)
        )
        ExposedDropdownMenuBox(expanded = isExpanded, onExpandedChange = { isExpanded = it }) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                value =
                    DateUtils.getPluralUnit(
                        context,
                        mainViewModel.periodUnit,
                        mainViewModel.recurringPeriod
                    ),
                onValueChange = {},
                readOnly = true,
                leadingIcon = {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.date_range),
                        contentDescription = null
                    )
                },
                trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = isExpanded) },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
                modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor()
            )
            Box {
                ExposedDropdownMenu(
                    expanded = isExpanded,
                    onDismissRequest = { isExpanded = false }
                ) {
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = {
                            Text(
                                text =
                                    if (mainViewModel.recurringPeriod.toInt() == 1)
                                        stringResource(R.string.day)
                                    else stringResource(R.string.days)
                            )
                        },
                        onClick = {
                            mainViewModel.periodUnit = context.resources.getString(R.string.day)
                            isExpanded = false
                        }
                    )
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = {
                            Text(
                                text =
                                    if (mainViewModel.recurringPeriod.toInt() == 1)
                                        stringResource(R.string.week)
                                    else stringResource(R.string.weeks)
                            )
                        },
                        onClick = {
                            mainViewModel.periodUnit = context.resources.getString(R.string.week)
                            isExpanded = false
                        }
                    )
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = {
                            Text(
                                text =
                                    if (mainViewModel.recurringPeriod.toInt() == 1)
                                        stringResource(R.string.month)
                                    else stringResource(R.string.months)
                            )
                        },
                        onClick = {
                            mainViewModel.periodUnit = context.resources.getString(R.string.month)
                            isExpanded = false
                        }
                    )
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = {
                            Text(
                                text =
                                    if (mainViewModel.recurringPeriod.toInt() == 1)
                                        stringResource(R.string.year)
                                    else stringResource(R.string.years)
                            )
                        },
                        onClick = {
                            mainViewModel.periodUnit = context.resources.getString(R.string.year)
                            isExpanded = false
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (state.periodError != null) {
        Text(
            text = state.periodError,
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        )
    }
}

Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

OutlinedButton(onClick = { mainViewModel.onEvent(AddTransactionEvent.OnAddClicked) }) {
    Icon(Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "add income")
    Text(text = stringResource(R.string.add), fontSize = 18.sp)
}
```

When I move the add button above the error message both are shown the same time

Comment: The text has `Modifier.fillMaxSize()`, so it takes all available space and none is left for the button.

Comment: Oh wow that is actually a stupid mistake of mine
Thank you so much !